# Tkinter not drawing image to canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

Tkinter doesn't draw image to canvas from another method.

Example 1 works, example 2 does not work. Can someone please explain why?

## example 1

```
def init_gui(self):
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.window, width=1000, height=500)

    photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=PIL.Image.fromarray(self.img))
    self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor=tkinter.NW)
    self.canvas.pack()

    window.mainloop()
    pass
```

## example 2

```
def init_gui(self):
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.window, width=1000, height=500)

    self._draw_img() # the exact same code, only in another method

    window.mainloop()
    pass
def _draw_img(self):
    photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=PIL.Image.fromarray(self.img))
    self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor=tkinter.NW)
    self.canvas.pack()
    pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember correctly, there's a problem in Tkinter when the image you're displaying goes out of scope (because it's a local variable). Try to make `photo` an attribute of your class (by replacing `photo` with `self.photo` in your `_draw_image` function) and see if that solves the issue.

Does this help?

**Edit**

For a more complete explanation, see this website: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm

Comment: Yep, that is how it works! I don't think it is a bug but more of a design choice, though.

Comment: If this is a design choice, it's a pretty bad one... People don't expect resources being freed even though they're still used in garbage-collected languages like Python. But this issue has been there for a long time, so it's not likely to be fixed soonish...

Comment: Correct. Here is a documentation link [https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#images]. "When the last Python reference to the image object is deleted, the image data is deleted as well, ..."

Comment: Yes it helps, tank you Felix and others :) ... Python is awesome... but tkinter, that is a whole other story...